# Switch bool from False to True on key press?

Tags: eventhandler, keyboard

I would like to let a boolean variable switch when I press a key on the keyboard.

For example, I write

```
activateE := Block[{}, edown = True;];
SetOptions[EvaluationNotebook[], NotebookEventActions -> {{"KeyDown", "e"} :> activateE}]
```

and then try to monitor the key presses via

```
edown = False;
Dynamic[edown]
```

While the key `e` now stops producing any text input into the notebook, unfortunately the `Dynamic` always keeps showing `False`, regardless how often I press the key `e`. What am I doing wrong, or how to do this properly?

EDIT:

Alternatively, I am trying the `CurrentValue` function. For example,

```
Dynamic[CurrentValue["ModifierKeys"]]
```

properly shows e.g. when the `Ctrl` key is being pressed. But if I try

```
Dynamic[CurrentValue["EventKey"]]
```

the output is `None` no matter which key I press. Is there an option of `CurrentValue` that would register a regular key press, like letter `e`?

EDIT2:

What seems to work, is

```
EventHandler[InputField[], {"KeyDown", "e"} :> activateE]
```

but only if I first click on the InputField to bring it into focus.

Comment: Use `{{"KeyDown", "e"} :> activateE` instead.

Comment: @CarlWoll Trying this, unfortunately I do not observe any difference in behavior. Does it work on your system? (I'll change the question to reflect this.)

Comment: try `NotebookEventActions -> {{"KeyDown", "e"} :> activateE, 
  PassEventsUp -> True}`?

Comment: It works fine for me in 11.1, 11.3 and 12.1. Maybe it is an OS thing?

Comment: This is strange, I'm on 11.3 Windows 10 and both suggestions above do not change the behavior. What seems to work though is `EventHandler[InputField[], {"KeyDown", "e"} :> activateE]`, but only if I first click on the `InputField` to bring it into focus.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using `NotebookEventActions` with the option `PassEventsUp -> True` gives the desired behavior in Version 11.3 (Windows 10 - 64 bit):

```
ClearAll[activateE]
activateE:=  Block[{}, edown = True;];
SetOptions[EvaluationNotebook[], 
 NotebookEventActions -> {{"KeyDown", "e"} :> activateE, PassEventsUp -> True}]
```

[image]

A variation: Toggle between `False` and `True` when key `e` is pressed:

[image]

```
$Version
```

> "11.3.0 for Microsoft Windows (64-bit) (March 7, 2018)"

Comment: Not sure what's wrong with my system, but normally this clearly seems to work.